# how to use Yii:t() inside placeholder in yii2 active form

Tags: yii2

i'm trying to use a placeholder in my form with i will also want to translate base of user's language so i wrap it up in a Yii::t(); inside active form input attribute but the result i got is a plane string rather than a translated message below is my code:

```
<div class="input-group custom-d-flex">
    <span class="input-group-addon input-group-prepend"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>                     
    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput([
                          'autofocus' => false,
                          'class' => 'form-control',
                          'required' => true,
                          'placeholder' => "<?= \Yii::t('app', 'email');?> / <?= \Yii::t('app', 'id');?> / <?= \Yii::t('app', 'phone');?>"
                    ])->label(false);
                    ?>
                </div>
```

and the result below[image]

how to fix this? thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholder expects string:

```
'placeholder' => \Yii::t('app', 'email') . ' / ' . \Yii::t('app', 'id') . ' / ' . \Yii::t('app', 'phone'),
```

Comment: thanks a lot you've just save my day, it works as expected i accept the answer